# Insert client with 0 bookings using a column that count only existing bookings

Tags: postgresql

I am making a query that shows the new clients sign up. One of the columns has to show the number of bookings that they have made. Some of them have 0 bookings.
The only way to count the booking is `count(booking_id)` and the `booking_id` is generated only when a booking is made, so I am not able to insert the value `0`, and those who did not place at least a booking are excluded from the list.

This below is a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT sign_up_date, client, count(booking_id_)
from client_table
group by 1, 2
```

These is the results that I'd like to have:

| Sign update | Client | count(booking_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 - 12 - 2021 | client 1 | 0 |
| 6 - 12 - 2021 | client 2 | 3 |
| 7 - 12 - 2021 | client 3 | 2 |
| 8 - 12 - 2021 | client 4 | 0 |

But I get the result below because the booking_id is generated only when a booking is created so I can’t  count those who have 0 bookings

| Sign up date | Client | count(booking_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 - 12 - 2021 | client 2 | 3 |
| 7 - 12 - 2021 | client 3 | 2 |

Comment: your query is not clear, what you actually expect? and what are you getting now? is there any entry without the booking_id? what is in that column for those entries?

Comment: what are you actually expecting? To exclude the ones with no booking? or what?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the previous answers as the question was ambiguous. As you confirmed the tables, the problem will be solved by this solution:

You need to do a `left join` to get all the `client` entries along with `null`-s in corresponding booking entries where clients has no bookings. Then a simple `group by` will do your job.

```
SELECT c.sign_up_date, c.client, count(b.booking_id_) as booking_count
from client c
left join booking b on b.client_id = c.client_id
group by 1, 2;
```

And this gives exactly what you want:

| sign_up_date | client | booking_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5-12-2021 | client 1 | 0 |
| 6-12-2021 | client 2 | 3 |
| 7-12-2021 | client 3 | 2 |
| 8-12-2021 | client 4 | 0 |

Comment: no I would like to add the booking_id  = 0, but at the moment they are not included because a booking_id code is generated only when a booking is created.

Comment: Please post the table definition (DDL) and the *input* (table contents). Just having the output is pretty useless.  You might want to spend a few minutes and review [ask].

Comment: @devReddit thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, as I am not the admin of the database I can't update the tables by entering null values. I am looking for a way to bypass this limitation.

Comment: can you tell me what these entries have in that `booking_id` column? I mean the data type and values

Comment: booking_id is a varchar numerical string such as 5,692 or 7,560.

Comment: I understand, but what about those who haven't booked anything yet?

Comment: they get a client_id but not a booking_id until they made a booking. every booking_id is related to a unique single booking.

Comment: That's what I am saying sir, let me break that more to you.

Those who have a booking is assigned a varchar of numerics in the `booking_id` column of that `client_table`.

What I am asking is, when you have a client without a booking, then what value is in the corresponding `booking_id` column of that entry in `client_table`. Is that a `null` or an empty data or something else? Or does that client have no entry in the `client_table`?

Comment: ok, so client_table is something I created to simplify the question. booking_id is on a table called "booking"  and client_id is on a table called "client". If a client makes a booking, the booking_id is generated in the "booking" table.

Comment: Sir, you made that question more difficult to understand by changing the whole scenario.
Anyways, so how the link works? Does `booking` table has `client_id` or the `client` table has booking id as reference? How do you map these two tables?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion 

Yes booking table has the foreign_key client_id:

SELECT 
client.sign_up_date, 
client.id,
count(booking.booking_id)

FROM client 
JOIN booking ON client.id = booking.client_id

GROUP BY 1, 2;

Comment: @devReddit thanks a lot! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RMolok if you think this answers your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) it.